# Google Cloud-Builder how to build all branches except for master

Tags: google-container-registry

I want to be able to build all branches that are not master, however when I try `^((?!master).)*$` the UI correctly shows all non-master branches but saving returns a HTTP 400 error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "trigger_template branch_name is not a valid regular expression",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is stupid ... but works by ignoring everything that starts with "master"

```
^(?:[^m]|m[^a]|ma[^s]|mas[^t]|mast[^e]|maste[^r]|master.)
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex used must be compatible with Go's regex library, which this one is not. (It is compatible with JavaScript, which is why the UI works with it.) https://regex101.com/ is useful for playing with different language parsers. (A teammate just showed it to me.) [Go's regex documentation is on GitHub](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Why? It doesn't answer the question