# Google Cloud Build - Trigger to invoke branch builds only

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I am trying to create a trigger which will only run when check-ins are done in a non-master branch. I provided the following regex in config

```
^(?!.*master).*$
```

But its failing with following error message

```
Invalid regex ^(?!.*master).*$: error parsing regexp: invalid or  unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`
```

Is there a way to give such regex without negative look ahead.

PS : When I chose docker option, it does give me a warning that "negative look ahead in regex is not supported"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud-Builder how to build all branches except for master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008616/google-cloud-builder-how-to-build-all-branches-except-for-master)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009108/7757976. It is posted by the Google Cloud Build Tech Lead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it works fine with

```
^master$
```

And then ticking the invert regex checkbox.

Comment: this is the true big brain answer

Answer (score 0):

Using this regex will ignore the master branch `[^(?!.*master)].*`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, error: "Dieser reguläre Ausdruck scheint Lookaheads zu enthalten, doch sie werden nicht unterstützt." (lookaheads are not supported)